# Trying to subtract hours from a certain time so it appears as the day before

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle-sqldeveloper

```
select  to_char(to_date(date1,'DD/MM/YYYY'), 'DAY') AS the_day, TO_CHAR(date1,'HH24:MI:SS') time_in, 
       (CASE WHEN TO_CHAR(date1,'HH24:MI:SS') between '06:00:00' AND '18:00:00'
             THEN 'day_shift'
             WHEN TO_CHAR(date1,'HH24:MI:SS') BETWEEN '00:00:00' AND '06:00:00'          
             THEN time_in - 6/24
             ELSE 'night_shift'
        END) AS shift
from blah;
```

My goal is to subtract 6 hours from  this part '00:00:00' AND '06:00:00' of the code. That way instead of it saying monday night shift it would say sunday night shift still for example. Just trying to have the day the shift exists on right dont care so much about time if that make sense.

Comment: So - you have a table "blah" with a field "date1" which has a date and time component; if it's a day shift fine, if not you want it to show the previous day... What if the time portion is exactly 6:00? The way you wrote the case expression, it would be shown as part of the day shift, and 18:00 would also be part of the day shift. Is this the business requirement?

Comment: Ill change the between statement but Im having the issue of the 0-6 morning shift but technically called the night shift so I want that night shift in the morning to be called sunday night shift instead of monday night shift. Figured subtracting 6 hours would make it appear as sunday

Comment: I think we'd be able to help you better if you also showed us some sample input data and expected output.

Comment: your problem is you don't know what you want -- I believe if the time is between midnight and 6am then you want to change **all three of the columns**.  Since this is true you need a case statement on each column.

Comment: Is date1 a date field or a text field?

Comment: date1 is for example 05:24:04

Comment: this is the error I get with my original code 'SUNDAY 05:24:04 night_shift' when I am trying to just get it so the day would be changed to saturday and appear as saturday nigh_shift even if the time is what it is

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For now I left date1 untouched, since it is not clear if in your data it is a string column or a date (datetime) column. You already know how to split it into date and time, so you may not need help with that.

**Query**:

```
with blah(date1) as (
        select to_date('2016-04-20 14:00:30', 'yyyy-mm-dd hh24:mi:ss') from dual union all
        select to_date('2016-04-20 19:00:30', 'yyyy-mm-dd hh24:mi:ss') from dual union all
        select to_date('2016-04-20 04:00:30', 'yyyy-mm-dd hh24:mi:ss') from dual
     )
select to_char(date1, 'yyyy-mm-dd hh24:mi:ss') as date1,
       case when date1 - trunc(date1) >= 6/24 then to_char(date1, 'DAY')
            else to_char(date1 - 1, 'DAY') end as day_of_week,
       case when date1 - trunc(date1) between 6/24 and 18/24 then 'Day Shift'
            else 'Night Shift' end as shift
from blah;
```

**Output**:

```
DATE1               DAY_OF_WEEK                          SHIFT
------------------- ------------------------------------ -----------
2016-04-20 14:00:30 WEDNESDAY                            Day Shift
2016-04-20 19:00:30 WEDNESDAY                            Night Shift
2016-04-20 04:00:30 TUESDAY                              Night Shift
```

Comment: Thank you so much that is exactly what I needed! I was unfamiliar with case because I just started sql and was already working with some complex problems haha

Comment: what exactly is trunc() function again?

Comment: trunc() applied to a number will truncate it (it will simply remove the decimal part). Applied to a datetime, think of the date portion as the integer part and the time portion as the fractional part. trunc(date) returns the same date, with the time portion changed to 00:00:00. The time portion is always there (there's no pure "date" in Oracle), but the time portion is midnight at the beginning of the day. `date1 - trunc(date1)` will return just the fractional part (hh:mi:ss) while canceling out the date portion. It's always expressed as a fraction of a day; 6 hours = 0.25.

Answer (score 0):

Your example doesn't actually make sense because you're mixing datatypes. I'm assuming date1 is a timestamp.

```
with blah as
 (select cast(to_date('2016-05-26 06:00:00', 'YYYY-MM-DD HH24:MI:SS') as timestamp) date1 from dual)
select to_char(case
                 when extract(hour from date1 - trunc(date1)) < 6 then
                  date1 - 1
                 else
                  date1
               end,
           'DAY'),
       case
         when extract(hour from date1 - trunc(date1)) < 6
              or extract(hour from date1 - trunc(date1)) >= 18 then
          'night_shift'
         else
          'day_shift'
       end
  from blah;
```